# Is it possible to detect strong light rays before they hit us? Can those light rays be strong enough to wipe out life on earth?

Tags: universe

Our observable universe is continually expanding, so as soon as a powerful source of light is within our horizon, it should be visible from earth. I know that light weakens with distance but

1. Would it be possible that the light the source emits is strong enough to wipe out life on earth?
2. Can we detect the light before it reaches earth?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the badly formatted question, I think this read might interest you:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst
As for your question regarding detecting a light traveling towards us by looking at changes in nearby planets: no. Information regarding changes in nearby planets would at best travel at the speed of light, meaning we would at best get the information at the same time the light hits us. 
Edit: removed some incorrect speculations according to comments.

Comment: I improved the formatting. Hopefully my questions are more clear now.

Comment: *Theoretically, maybe you could use some entanglement to detect changes instantly, but actually realizing that is...not easy.* Absolutely no: it is a [well known no-go theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) that quantum entanglement cannot be used for faster-than-light communication. I'd suggest removing that last phrase, as the answer was perfectly fine until that point.